# How to describe new array with a certain name after running the code?

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

I am building up some easy stuff but already got an error.

In summary : when my code running user will write some sentence to the cmd  and my code will separate it to words. 
It is alright so far. After separating, I want to make arrays for each word 
for example :

```
cmd screen =" hello world  "  
seperating to words =  hello , world
making them arrays (program should do these aoutomatically)  
string[] hello = new string[5]
```

and

```
string[] world = new string[5]
```

Here is where the problem starts. I want to name those new arrays after running. You will write "apple" to cmd and new array with name "apple" should pop out. Already asked for my teacher about this and he says it can be done with dynamic valuables (with var etc). But  I don't know how. Here my codes so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> tümkelimeler = new List<string>();


            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                tümkelimeler.Insert(i, "null");
            }

            int ü = 0;
            while (ü == 0) 
            {

                string s = Console.ReadLine();


               string[] kelimeler = s.Split(' ');
                // this is where i seperate words from sentence . 


            }

 Console.ReadKey() ;
        }

    }
}

    #Complete Code
```

Comment: Just so you know, you pretty much don't want to do this. Ever. *Especially* when you are just learning. This kind of code reeks of bad design/practices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing one way of doing it using dynamic ExpandoObject. We keep adding dynamic properties with string name and array values.

Showing for one sentence, you can run a loop and do it for as many sentences you want.

```
using System.Dynamic;

string s = "hello world"; //example
IDictionary<string, object> dynamicArrays = new ExpandoObject();

string[] words = s.Split(' '); //hello, world
foreach(var word in words)
{
    dynamicArrays[word] = word.Select(c => new String(new char[] { c })).ToArray();
}
```

What it does in the loop is: For each word, it creates a new property in the object with the word (e.g. "hello") as the name. Then it breaks down the same word as a letter (string) array (h, e, l, l, o) and adds that as the value of the same property.

If you see the dynamic object `dynamicArrays`, it will have following properties

```
hello: ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
world: ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

See the [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) reference here.

---

**Update**

If you want to do that for multiple user input, you can do like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = string.Empty;
    IDictionary<string, object> dynamicArrays = new ExpandoObject();

    Console.WriteLine("Keep entering words/sentences. Enter blank/empty line to end.");
    s = Console.ReadLine();

    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        string[] words = s.Split(' '); //hello, world
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            dynamicArrays[word] = word.Select(c => new String(new char[] { c })).ToArray();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter next sentence : ");
        s = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // do something with dynamicArrays
    return;
}
```

Here, if you enter three values : `hello world`, `apple`, `green tiger` then this is what you'll get in dynamicArrays object.

```
{
  "hello": [ "h", "e", "l", "l", "o" ],
  "world": [ "w", "o", "r", "l", "d" ],
  "apple": [ "a", "p", "p", "l", "e" ],
  "green": [ "g", "r", "e", "e", "n" ],
  "tiger": [ "t", "i", "g", "e", "r" ]
}
```

Comment: thank you for ur detailed answer . but how to do this                         cmd screen =" hello world  "  
seperating to words =  hello , world
      string[] x = new string[5]                                                                                 after runing code   i will write "apple" to the console . and  "x" will became " apple" .

Comment: @EnesKuz I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but if you want to take multiple user input and do it for all inputs, see my **update** -ed answer